# Sonarlint and Intelij: possible to run analysis only for files in a changelist?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am currently running `sonarlint` plugin locally in `Intelij` which works well.

I would like to run the plugin *only* for files that I have in my Changelist - before I push them and create a Pull request.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this

Select Analyze list and then choose Analyze VCS changed files with SonarLint

[image]

Comment: This menu entry doesn't seem to be present anymore (by default?). But you can also execute it via the _Find Actions_ Dialog.

Answer (score 5):

Select the changelist in the Git window. Then click ctrl-shift-S